# How to handle token refresh with redux observable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I've been learning rxjs and have put together a token refresh flow that works, but I'd like to make some improvements and am stuck.

```
export const makeApiRequest = <
  T extends (p: StandardAdminParams) => Promise<Request.ApiResult<any>>
>(
  req: T,
  params: RemainingApiCallArgs<T>,
  action$: ActionsObservable<any>,
  state$: StateObservable<RootState>
) =>
  mergeMap(() =>
    defer(() =>
      req({
        ...params,
        settings,
        token: getToken(state$.value)!
      })
    ).pipe(
      mergeMap(async v => {
        const resp = await v;
        if (!resp.ok) {
          // TODO find out if there's a better way here.
          throw resp.error;
        }

        return resp as ApiReturnType<T>;
      }),
      catchError((_, source) => {
        // TODO make this actually check if token is refreshing, etc.
        return action$.pipe(
          filter(isActionOf(authActions.refreshToken.success)),
          takeUntil(action$.ofType(AuthActionConsts.REFRESH_TOKEN_FAILED)),
          take(1),
          mergeMap(() => source),
          merge(of(authActions.refreshToken.request()))
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

My API library doesn't throw exceptions, it returns `ok: boolean`. All the examples of refresh token tutorials I've found however, take advantage of the `catchError()` operator to allow for retrying the call on successful refresh. I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same thing without having to throw a "fake" error here.

Here's an example use case:

```
const fetchCurrentEmployeeEpic: Epic<ActionTypes, any, RootState> = (
  action$,
  state$
) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.requestCurrentEmployee.request)),
    makeApiRequest(Employees.getSingle, {}, action$, state$),
    mapApiResponse(v => {
      if (v.ok) {
        return actions.requestCurrentEmployee.success({
          employee: v.value.data
        });
      }
      return actions.requestCurrentEmployee.failure({
        error: v.error
      });
    })
  );
```

and `mapApiResponse` handles both outputs, either a refresh action or the return type of the api call. Open to suggestions on a better way to do this:

```
type RefreshTokenAction = ReturnType<typeof authActions.refreshToken.request>;

// Remove refresh token action type from union because our map function is only going to ever receive API responses.
type ExpectedMapParams<
  T extends Request.ApiResult<any> | RefreshTokenAction
> = T extends RefreshTokenAction ? never : T;

/**  Pass through refresh token action, otherwise pass api result to our callback */
export const mapApiResponse = <
  T extends Request.ApiResult<any> | RefreshTokenAction,
  R extends Action
>(
  cb: (params: ExpectedMapParams<T>) => R
) =>
  map((v: T) => {
    if (isRefreshAction(v)) {
      return v;
    }

    return cb(v as ExpectedMapParams<T>);
  });

const isRefreshAction = <T extends Request.ApiResult<any> | RefreshTokenAction>(
  v: T
): v is ExpectedMapParams<T> => {
  if (isAction(v)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

However I've discovered another problem - I can't use the passed action to format a payload (for ids, etc.) Is there another way to get the action as a parameter so that I can pass a callback to params, i.e.

```
export const makeApiRequest = <
  T extends (p: StandardAdminParams) => Promise<Request.ApiResult<any>>
>(
req: T,
params: (action: GETACTIONTYPEHERE) => RemainingApiCallArgs<T>,
  action$: ActionsObservable<any>,
  state$: StateObservable<RootState>
) =>
```

EDIT: I managed to figure out the action payload signature by doing the following:

```
export const makeApiRequest = <
  T extends (p: any) => Promise<Request.ApiResult<any>>,
  K extends Action
>(
  req: T,
  params: RemainingApiCallArgs<T> | ((p: K) => RemainingApiCallArgs<T>),
  action$: ActionsObservable<any>,
  state$: StateObservable<RootState>
) =>
  mergeMap((action: K) =>
    defer(() => {
      const formattedParams =
        typeof params === "function" ? params(action) : params;
      return req({
        ...formattedParams,
        settings,
        token: getToken(state$.value)!
      });
    }).pipe(
    ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: `mergeMap` is an operator. Are you intending for `makeApiRequest` to be a custom, pipeable operator (which is what the example accomplishes)? Or are you intending for `makeApiRequest` to be a function that creates a new observable?

Comment: Additionally, can you clarify the expected return type of `makeApiRequest` (since it's not explicitly declared)? Right now, the inner `mergeMap` returns a `ApiReturnType<T>`, but the `catchError` returns an `Observable<Action>`. Are you intending to mix the return type and have the caller deal with these different cases?

Comment: Yes, I'm intending to make it pipeable, I'll append with an example.

Comment: It might make more sense to have it return an observable, but I'm not sure. This is a pattern I'll be using throughout the entire app so I want to set it up right. I need to wrap an api call to get the token etc from state, attempt it, refresh token if it fails & retry, and pass the results to a map that will decide which action to output.

Answer (score 0):

In the original version of `makeApiRequest`, it feels a bit odd to create a custom operator. First, it doesn't actually *operate* on anything emitted by the source observable. Second, it uses hard-coded request parameters. You appear to have identified and addressed these concerns in the edited version.

Whether you emit an error and use `catchError` or emit two different types of items and check the type is really a question about coding style. They both work, and it's akin to the difference between this:

```js
function fetchCurrentEmployee() {
  const result = makeApiRequest()
  if (isRefreshAction(result)) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

... and this:

```js
function fetchCurrentEmployee() {
  try {
    const resp = makeApiRequest()
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The difference is that, with the try-catch route, you simply don't need the `isRefreshAction` check. If you apply this to your epics/operators and emit an error, `mapApiResponse` simply reduces to a plain `map` operator.

Comment: Really at the end of the day, I want a way to 

1) do some initial checks to see if I need to make the API request and emit an action  + skip the request if not
2) If the request fails due to an expired token, emit an action that kicks off the refresh flow in another epic
3) Wait for the refresh epic to complete, and if successful retry the API request
4) Emit either success or failure actions depending on the result of the API request. The actions themselves will vary depending on which request is made.

So far, I'm unable to resolve part 1 with this flow....